Relationship Friends table SQLModel
I am trying to make friends table and I feel that I am not doing it the correct way, having user_id and friend_id and then user and friend. Also if that is the correct way how to make sure the user_id is the one for the user as well as for friend_id and friend. Also what arguments should I fill in the Relationship.
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Relationship, Index
from sqlalchemy import CheckConstraint
from user import User

class Friends(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "friends"
    user_id: int = Field(foreign_key="users.id", primary_key=True, ondelete="CASCADE")
    friend_id: int = Field(foreign_key="user.id", primary_key=True, ondelete="CASCADE")
    
    user: User = Relationship(.....)
    friend: User = Relationship(....)
    __table_args__ = (
        Index("idx_friends_user_id", "user_id"),
        Index("idx_friends_friend_id", "friend_id"),
        CheckConstraint('user_id != friend_id', name='check_user_id_not_equal_friend_id')
    )

